# geoip_record_by_name returns nothing?

Tags: php, ubuntu, geolocation

I tried this tutorial http://tech.cibul.net/install-maxminds-geoip-ip-database-on-ubuntu-for-php/ and did everything from it. Compiled the geoip module and also the php extension on my Ubuntu 11.10 installation.

I also tried this more simpler terminal command

```
(sudo) apt-get install php5-geoip
```

And it showed successful installation but when I try

```
geoip_record_by_name('127.0.0.1')
```

and it still gives nothing, i.e. no array at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a different IP address - for example `111.111.111.111` as you are checking your localhost (`127.0.0.1`) - it may not run locally anyway.

See [`geoip_record_by_name`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/geoip_record_by_name):

> Returns the associative array on success, or `FALSE` if the address cannot be found in the database.

You get back `FALSE` because the address was not found in the database.

Answer (score 1):

There is important discussion on this subject at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59753

The problem with this function is that it returns a "PHP Notice" when a address can not be found.

In plain the behavior this function take on normal internal address that is not expected to return location ( record ) from its database is to return "false" that is good and expected, but additional it send "PHP Notice" that is normally used to report real coding or library problems, but not expected results.